Firebase Realtime Database Web - myref.on is not a function
I'm using Firebase Realtime Database for Web in JavaScript.
Here is my HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Realtime</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Realtime</h1>
  <script type="module">
    import { initializeApp } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-app.js';
    import { getDatabase, ref, push } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.10.0/firebase-database.js';
    
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "..."
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getDatabase(app);
  var myref = ref(db, "Chat");
  
  myref.on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
        console.log("New child added: ", snapshot.val());
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        push(myref, { u: "user", m: "abc" });
    }, 5000);
</script>
</body>
</html>

The problem is that myref.on is not a function. How do I solve this?
onValue() reads both existing data and keeps track when a data is added, but I want two seperate functions for this, not mixed.
After 5 seconds, a new message will be pushed (for testing).
Your answer will be greatly appreciated.

You're mixing the syntax of the modular API (which uses top-level functions) with the syntax of the namespaced API, which isn't possible. In the modular API, import onValue and use onValue(ref, ... instead of ref.on(....

onValue() reads both existing data and keeps track when a data is added, but I want seperate functions for this, not mixed.

Ah, in that case onChildAdded. Also check out the code-samples here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events
